# Renaming Local Area Connections

Tags: windows, lan

I have multiple applications that assume that the two Ethernet Ports on the single board computer are named "Local Area Connection" and "Local Area Connection 2". I am working with a new single board computer now that has two ethernet ports but those come up as "Local Area Connection 3" and "Local Area Connection 4".

I tried to rename "Local Area Connection 3" to "Local Area Connection" and "Local Area Connection 4" to "Local Area Connection 2" using the steps here:  https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19664-network-connection-change-name-windows-8-a.html

Option #1 gives me an error that a connection with the name I specified already exists.

Option #2 gives me the same error.

So I guess I need to remove all traces of the existing "Local Area Connection" and "Local Area Connection 2". This is where I need help

Comment: I've had this problem, and the only solution I found was to find the registry settings and do my deletions and renaming from there. If you do this, set a restore point first and restart after making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to remove the "ghosted" devices using those names.

From an elevated command prompt:

```
Set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1
Start devmgmt.msc
```

Device manager will open. From View Menu choose Show Hidden Devices.

Now expand your network adapters node and delete the ghosted Local Area Connection 1 and 2.

If you still can't rename them, delete them all, then reboot Windows. It will reinstall them as 1 and 2.